# C# - Picking a data structure for storage of memory from a periphieral device

Tags: c#, memory, data-structures, struct

I have approximately 50 bytes worth of memory that I would like to hold on to from a peripheral device. I have 10 of these peripheral devices and each one has 5 "channels". (Each channel has its own 50 bytes worth of memory).

My first thought would be to create a two dimensional array of structs, each struct would have a bool for validity (which would be set last) and an array of 50 bytes. I could access this array as follows: myStruct[DEVICE][CHANNEL].arrayOfBytes[i];

However, I am new to C# (and programming in general). From some quick reading it seems like the use of structs is frowned upon in C#. What is the ideal way to do something like this in a language like C#?

Comment: If you're new to C# I'd suggest a good rule of thumb is to stick to using a class if it will serve your purpose (and for the vast majority of things, it will). Where you find using a class gives you a specific problem you need to solve by using a struct, only then consider using one. Using structs in your example isn't wrong, but you'd have to question whether they provide a real benefit to justify the gotchas they come with. [This question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/92339/when-do-you-use-a-struct-instead-of-a-class) is a good read.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to a struct here is a class, with the primary difference that matters for this question being that your data is more likely to end up on the heap instead of the stack with a class.

In my opinion, though, this is an okay use of structs. Generally, I've heard that you want to keep structs down to about 20 bytes, and since the array is a reference type you're well within that.

Comment: But the struct would only be 4 or 8 bytes long (size of a reference), because the array is a reference object. Unless he uses a fixed-size array ... no, let's not go down that path.

Comment: Very good point. I don't know why I was thinking the array size would be part of the struct. I know better :/

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest a two-dimensional array unless you know for sure that your devices will always be numbered sequentially. If you can have devices 1, 8, and 12, then you'll be wasting a lot of space. Same with channels. Even if things are numbered sequentially now, it's possible that they could change in the future.

Depending on how fast access needs to be, you might consider creating multiple classes to hold this information. Something like:

```
public class Channel
{
    public int ChannelNumber {get; private set;}
    public byte[] ChannelData {get; set; }
    // constructor, etc.
}

public class Device
{
    public int DeviceNumber {get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<int, Channel> Channels {get; private set; }
    // constructor, etc.
}
```

And your main program contains a dictionary of devices:

```
public Dictionary<int, Device> Devices;
```

So `Devices` is indexed by device number, and within a `Device`, `Channels` is accessed by channel number. This allows flexibility in the layout of devices and channels.

To get the information for a particular device/channel, you'd call a function like this:

```
public byte[] GetChannelInfo(int deviceId, int channelId)
{
    Device device;
    if (!Devices.TryGetValue(deviceId, out device))
    {
        // error, device doesn't exist.
    }
    Channel channel;
    if (!device.Channels.TryGetValue(channelId, out channel))
    {
        // error, channel does not exist on that device
    }
    return channel.ChannelData;
}
```

Now, that looks like it might be messy, but it really isn't. Rather than:

```
var data = MyArrayOfStructs[0,0].Data;
```

You have:

```
var data = GetChannelInfo(0, 0);
```

That gives you a lot more flexibility at some relatively small cost in performance.